# How to install .NET Language Pack on Azure Web App?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, data-annotations

I'm working on a website that uses System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

On my local machine, model validation messages are displayed in french but they are in english wehn I deploy the website to Azure.

How can I install Microsoft .NET Language Pack on my Azure Web App ?
Or, is it possible to find the french System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.resources.dll and deploy it with the website ? When I put this assembly in the /bin/ folder, it does not change anything. Validation messages are still in en-US.

Comment: If you need DataAnnotations messages to be in your language on your Azure Web App, please vote for my idea on the Azure feedback website : http://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps-formerly-websites/suggestions/9854277-provide-net-language-packs-on-web-apps